# Validation type not achieved when calling ajax.post

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I want to validate some fields before sending the model to my Action.

This is the textboxfor I want to validate

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(cModel => cModel.Value, new { id = "txtbLimit", @type = "int" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(cModel => cModel.Value)
```

And the ajax post:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("AddUpdateConfigs")',
    {QueueMonitorConfigurationsID: ident, QueueMonitorConfigTypeName: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(), Threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(), QueueMonitorValueTypeName:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(), Location: $('#txtbLocation').val(), Value: $('#txtbLimit').val()},
    function(data){
        if (!data.Success){
            alert(data.Description);
        }
        else{
            //$('#gridView').load('/Storage/gvConfigurations');
            $.get('@Url.Action("gvConfigurations", "Storage")',null,function(data){$('#gridView').html(data);},'html');
        }
    },'json');
```

And the function it calls:

```
public JsonResult AddUpdateConfigs(StorageConfigurationModel modelbind)
{
    //Take the list of configurations
    IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel> configList = (IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel>)Session["ConfigurationList"];
    //Loop
    foreach (StorageConfigurationModel configModel in configList)
    {
        //Is it a duplicated entry?
        if ((configModel.QueueMonitorConfigTypeName == modelbind.QueueMonitorConfigTypeName) && (configModel.Location == modelbind.Location) && (configModel.QueueMonitorValueTypeName == modelbind.QueueMonitorValueTypeName) && (configModel.Threshold == modelbind.Threshold))
        {
            //Found duplicated entry
            return Json(new { Success = false, Description = "Duplicate entry" });
        }
    }
    //If not duplicated, add it to DB

    try
    {
        if (modelbind.Location.StartsWith("\\"))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(modelbind.Location);
            if (dir.Exists)
            {
                int finalValue = 0;
                int pathInt = 0;
                int valueTypeInt = 0;

                if (modelbind.QueueMonitorConfigTypeName == PathType.Path)
                    pathInt = 1;
                else
                    pathInt = 2;
                switch (modelbind.QueueMonitorValueTypeName)
                {
                    case UnitType.Percentage:
                        valueTypeInt = 1;
                        break;
                    case UnitType.MB:
                        valueTypeInt = 2;
                        break;
                    case UnitType.GB:
                        valueTypeInt = 3;
                        break;
                    case UnitType.TB:
                        valueTypeInt = 4;
                        break;
                    case UnitType.Files:
                        valueTypeInt = 5;
                        break;
                }

                if (modelbind.Threshold == ThresholdType.Upper)
                    finalValue = modelbind.Value;
                else
                    finalValue = Convert.ToInt32("-" + modelbind.Value);
                Boolean result = false;
                result = DAL.queryAddUpdateConfig(modelbind.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID, pathInt, modelbind.Location, finalValue, valueTypeInt);
                return Json(new { Success = result, Description = (result) ? ((modelbind.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID == -1) ? "New data inserted" : "Data updated") : "Error in Data types" });

            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, Description = "Location Path is not correct" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false, Description = "Location Path has to be UNC path" });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception j)
    {
        return Json(new { Success = false, Description = "Error: " + j });
    }
}
```

It is smart enough to bing the model but not to make the validation.
If I put a string in the textboxfor where a value (int) should be, it converts it to 0 and not doing the validation.

I also have validation for the Location with a regular expression...again not working.

Anyone see anything wrong? Thank you

EDIT:

I have:

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "form" }))
    {}
```

And this before the ajax post:

```
$('#form').validate();
```

Comment: You jQuery selector '#form' is invalid - it select element with ID="form" instead element that is the form. Please use `form` without hash

Comment: my code is correct because it validates but throws a JS error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see checking in your code if `ModelState.IsValid`. Additionally you should invoke

```
$('form').validate();
```

to validate your form on client-side or even use `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: Did it but I get a js error:
`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined`

Comment: Do you have fields wrapped by form? You must wrap fields with `Html.BeginFrom` or `Ajax.BeginForm` if you want client-side validation or you must configure jQuery validation by yourself.